gmail login failure with Thunderbird, username and password are correct
OS 24.04, Thunderbird 128.0esr running on HP Elitebook I am unable to log in to gmail, always getting Authentication failure, username or password incorrect. I have verified with google that my password is right and I know my username. My settings are smtp.gmail.com, SSL/TLS port 465 and the incoming is imap.gmail.com, port 993, SSL/TLS using normal password for authentication. I am able to use webmail with no problems. What am I doing wrong? This has just cropped up in the last few days.

Doesn't gmail require OAuth2?

Yes, or set an "app password".

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail

@quill, I changed "normal password" to OAuth2 on incoming and outgoing servers, restarted the computer, and voila! I have no understanding of this and do not recall seeing the recommendation...everything I looked at said "normal password". I believe you have solved my problem. ty.

gmail requires use of OAuth2 rather than traditional passwords.  I use the POP3 type.  Some time ago it seemed like I was getting regular email from Google saying my technique for getting mail was legacy.  Then they set a date to cut off email such as Thunderbird if  OAuth2 wasn't used for authentication.

My efforts with gmail were guided by online help for gmail settings and consistently were the settings I was trying. Am glad for your passing this info on. This adventure all began with issues I was having with Zitomedia, my service provider. All's well, now.
